# TPOT: TPOTRegressor is showing Name Error

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.7, nameerror, train-test-split, tpot

Here is the code I am running about **TPOTRegressor**.

```
from tpot import TPOTRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

housing = sklearn.datasets.load_boston()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(housing.data, housing.target,
                                                    train_size=0.75, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

tpot = TPOTRegressor(generations=5, population_size=50, verbosity=2, random_state=42)
tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(tpot.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-a52aaaaedc24> in <module>
      8 
      9 tpot = TPOTRegressor(generations=5, population_size=50, verbosity=2, random_state=42)
---> 10 tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)
     11 print(tpot.score(X_test, y_test))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tpot\base.py in fit(self, features, target, sample_weight, groups)
    637         features, target = self._check_dataset(features, target, sample_weight)
    638 
--> 639         self._init_pretest(features, target)
    640 
    641         # Randomly collect a subsample of training samples for pipeline optimization process.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tpot\tpot.py in _init_pretest(self, features, target)
     65 
     66         """
---> 67         self.pretest_X, _, self.pretest_y, _ = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=self.random_state,
     68                                                                 test_size=None, train_size=min(50,int(0.9*features.shape[0])))

NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

For some reason the code returns this NameError which says X is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in tpot v0.11.2. Uninstalling and re-installing to the latest tpot v0.11.3 solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue. There is a very simple bug in the code, simply:

- open the tpot.py file referenced in the log
- then change the X, y in TPOTRegressor to features, target respectively
- save the change and you should be good to go

I got mine working just fine.